# Python cdecimal.Decimal and SQLAlchemy _mysql_exceptions.Warning

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, decimal

I am building a django app that uses SQLAlchemy over MySQL. I am using cdecimal instead of the built in Decimal.
In one of my tables, I have a Numeric value column (`value = Column(Numeric(10, 5)`).
When I create a new entry for this table in my django app, with the following SQL echo:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (date, value) VALUES (2012-03-11, 875334.670)
```

This causes the following exception to be thrown upon commit:

```
_mysql_exceptions.Warning: Out of range value for column 'value' at row 1
```

When I run the same query in the mysql client, no issues at all.
I even tried wrapping the code that adds the entry with:

```
import warnings
from sqlalchemy import exc as sa_exc
with warnings.catch_warnings():
        warnings.simplefilter("ignore", category=sa_exc.SAWarning)
```

What is going on?

Thanks!

Comment: Will you please give the example to create the problem in our system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the issue:

```
>>> import cdecimal
>>> cdecimal.Decimal(1.23)
Decimal('1.229999999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875')
>>> cdecimal.Decimal('1.23') 
Decimal('1.23')
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (date, value) VALUES ('2012-03-11', 875334.670)
```

Comment: hey - thanks, but I am not actually executing the SQL command - SQLAlchemy is doing it for me, and the query above was echoed by SQLAlchemy..